# calling both the parent and child objects separately in OOP

Tags: java, php, oop

Thought I was ok at OOP but seem to have hit a stumbling block.

In this example I have a Car and BMW and a Audi. The Car has a set of behaviour and the BMW and Audi inherits off Car separately.

```
---Car---
| ----- |
----------
BMW --- Audi
```

When the user creates a object they do this through the child classes, eg new BMW. This is fine as the BMW has different attributes and ways of retrieving and storing these attributes. However on the next screen I want to display the Car (could be either BMW or Audi), so essentially here I want to do Car->getName() for example, baring in mind the BMW's name is stored differently to an Audi's name. How do I achieve this? I could use case statements however I really don't want to do this as I don't think it's good practise. Any ideas?

Comment: `carInstance.getName()`?

Comment: @Keyser not exactly the reason but Audi is stored in an audio table and BMW is stored in a BMW table. Sound like an awful structure but without going into loads of detail I've done it this way!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `getName()` an abstract method. Make `Car` an abstract class so that it can't be instantiated. Then in the `Audi` and `BMW` subclasses, override the `getName()` method to correctly return the name.

This is all assuming Java, but I'm sure PHP has similar OOP concepts.

EDIT: It seems that you might need a factory. First, make Car abstract. Then, have this method somewhere (like a static method in Car).

```
public Car carFactory(DB database) {
    if (DB.shouldMakeAudi()) {
        return new Audi();
    } else if (DB.shouldMakeBMW()) {
        return new BMW();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way I envisaged it but on the page where I am displaying the Car I do not know whether it is a BMW or an Audi at that point so I need to call the Car class so it can't be abstract.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean. Why do you need to know the type of the Car? If it's a Car, you can call the methods of a Car.

Comment: true but the getName method is different from both the BMW and Audi

Comment: That's the point. The same method will return a different name depending on what type of Car it is. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yea! Am I missing something major here but if I call new Car() how will it know it's a BMW? I won't be able to know if it's a BMW or an Audi at that point?

Comment: If you call `new Car()` then you can't know if it's an Audi or a BMW because *it isn't either of those*. It's just a plain car. If you want your car to have a specific type, then again, you need to make Car abstract and only instantiate child classes.

Comment: I see. I guess the crux of this problem that I have a type id in the the cars table (Audi and BMW), is there a best practice way of instantiating a Car as one of these dependant on the type stored in the database?

Comment: Yes! You need what's called a factory. You give it some piece of information (like a database) and it returns a specific type of car. I'll give a quick example in my answer.

Comment: That sounds exactly what is needed! Shame I had to go round the houses (or in this case cars) to get my problem out haha! Thanks so much, I'll await your answer!

Answer (score 0):

well the class CAR can be consist of an method say getName(); which sets the value in class property $_carName;

```
class car {
 protected $_carName;

 protected function getCarName(){
    return $this->_carName;
 }
}
```

so, now you will do is set $_carName with the setter functions inside child classes. And whenever you want to fetch the carname, you can use each child classInstance to get respective carname.

Comment: `return $this -> _carName;`

Answer (score 0):

You could have your Car class, like this:

```
public abstract class Car {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Let your BMW and Audi inherit your Car, and include any BMW and Audi specific name here:

```
public class BMW extends Car {

    private String bmwSpecificName;

}

public class Audi extends Car {

    private String AudiSpecificName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the abstract class Car, Audio and BMW. They are simplified for explaining. If you want to extract the name of an object, you simply call getName. In this example it absolutely doesn't matter how the name is stored internally by BMW or Audio. You get an object of the static type Car (could be either one of BMW or Audio as the actual type) and just call `getName()`.

```
<?php

abstract class Car {
    /**
     * Returns the name of the car.
     * @return string
     */
    abstract function getName();
}

class BMW extends Car {
    public function getName() {
        return 'bmw';
    }
}

class Audio extends Car {
    public function getName() {
        return 'audio';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As you said it's bad practice but if you really want to do it as you described you could do it like so (works for Java):

```
//in Audi class
String methodToGetAudiName();

//in BMW class
String methodToGetBMWName();

if (carInstance instanceof Audi)
stringToStoreName = ((Audi)carInstance).methodToGetAudiName();
else if (carInstance instanceof BMW)
stringToStoreName = ((BMW)carInstance).methodToGetBMWName();
```

Comment: But why on Earth, while they have a common ancestor?

Comment: You are absolutely right. But I understood he wanted to do it without just overriding a method getName() in the abstract class Car or just store it in a common field in the superclass. But if he only ment not having the common field, I apologize for suggesting this non OOP way :)

Comment: Sorry, but there's absolutely no reason in the world to do this. And if you can think of a reason, it's only because your class design is terrible. If you ever find yourself doing something like this, delete your code and start over.

Comment: But there is no problem in overriding the `getName()`method, that's what inheritance is for ^^

Comment: Right, guess I misunderstood the question (happens too often to me ...). And @GJK, you're absolutely correct!!!